# Creating Pascal's Triangle using Python Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.4

I'm working on a homework assignment that asks me to create a Pascal Triangle using a recursive function. Below is what I've managed so far along with what I was given to work with. I'm quite new to Python and programming so I've got no idea where to head from here, any help would be appreciated!

```python
def combination(n, k):
    print((n - 1) / (k - 1)) + ((n - 1) / k)

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    for row in range(rows):
        answer = ""
        for column in range(row + 1):
            answer = answer + combination(row, column) + "\t"
        print(answer)

pascals_triangle(5)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem that you cannot resolve, at this point?

Comment: it looks like you expect ```combination(row, column)``` to return a string, but it just prints to the terminal and then returns ```None```

Comment: @Donkey Kong I'm getting a ZeroDivisionError and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @RialJohnson you're getting divide by zero because ```range(n)``` iterates from ```0``` to ```n-1```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not, in fact, using recursion at all in your answer. I think you are trying to code the formula nCk = (n-1)C(k-1) + (n-1)Ck. You need, therefore, to call `combination` from within itself (with a guard for the "end" conditions: nC0 = nCn = 1):

```
def combination(n, k):
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1
    return combination(n - 1, k - 1) + combination(n - 1, k)

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    for row in range( rows):
        answer = ""
        for column in range( row + 1):
            answer = answer + str(combination(row, column)) + "\t"
        print(answer)

pascals_triangle(5)
```

Output:

```
1   
1   1   
1   2   1   
1   3   3   1   
1   4   6   4   1
```

Note that this is a spectacularly inefficient way of doing this: you are calling `combination` many, many times with the same arguments each time you get a binomial coefficient. You might consider caching the coefficients you find as you go along.

The other problem with your code is that your `combination` function wasn't actually returning anything, it was simply printing a value and exiting (returning `None`).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for what I needed! After doing a lot more reading about recursion (I'm a student and very new to Python) I was able to come close to the solution you gave, but your explanation definitely helped a lot!